# Assets orderby Title

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

I can't seem to be able to sort Asset files by their title, instead only by their filename through `orderby="name"`.

Is it possible to use the Title field for ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pixel & Tonic support, the below alteration to the plugin can support this, in case anyone is interested.

**third_party/assets/libraries/Assets_lib.php:765**

Replace

```
$order_by = in_array(strtolower($order_by), array('name', 'folder', 'date', 'size', 'file_id', 'date_modified')) ? strtolower($order_by) : false;
```

With

```
$order_by = in_array(strtolower($order_by), array('name', 'folder', 'date', 'size', 'file_id', 'date_modified', 'title')) ? strtolower($order_by) : false;
```

Then in the switch statement on line 913, add the following:

```
case 'title':
{
    $sql .= 'ORDER BY exp_assets_files.title ' . $order_type;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. According to the [docs](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/module/files.html#tag-parameters) you can only order by file_id, name, folder, date, and size.